# SharePoint Choice Fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column

I have a list that has a multiple choice field (more than one choice can be selected) and I want to query that field to find out how many of the choices were selected.

So if the field has 5 choices and a user select 2 of the 5 choices, I want to store 2 in the calculated field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use multiple selection choice columns in SharePoint calculated column formula.

If you just want to show how many choices are selected/not selected in the list view (not going to use this value anywhere else in the list or custom solution), you can use JSON formatting like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=length([$ChoiceCol])"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

If you have total 5 choices in choice column settings, you can use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=(5-length([$ChoiceCol]))"
}
```

Where `ChoiceCol` is an [internal name of your SharePoint choice column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

**Reference**: [SPO Count column](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/spo-count-column/m-p/3744166)